# Ui automator viewer--> Device screenshot, Reason : Error while creating temporary file to save snapshot : null

Tags: android, appium

When I click on Ui automator viewer after connecting my mobile device--> Device screenshot throws error

Error : 
Error obtaining UI hierarchy  Reason : Error while creating temporary file to save snapshot : null

Please let me know how to fix this issue?. Thanks

Comment: Are any of your automation tools running (eg:appium)while trying to capture the screenshot to identify elements?If so,these use the same adb ports that the uiautomator viewer uses.Close these tools and try to capture the screenshot.It must work

Comment: Thanks for sharing information. Checked again with all automation tools closed but still prblm didnt solved. Please help me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you post your error screenshots and also the list of processes running while trying to obtain the screenshot?Also the answer by @vinod below has helped me a few times

Answer (score 2):

Download an old version of platform tools [from Google](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.0-windows.zip)

copy `adb.exe` and replace with current one in your SDK tools.

Source: https://softwaretestingboard.com/q2a/1654/appium-automator-viewer-could-android-emulators-screenshot#ixzz5qS8ez6GY

Answer (score 0):

Take the screenshot and dump manually and open from "uiautomator". It will work. Use below commands to create and pull the dump from device:

```
-> adb shell uiautomator dump
-> adb pull /sdcard/window_dump.xml
```

Go to Ui automator, then select open file, select screenshot and corresponding dump xml file. Now we can see all the elements in UiAutomator tool.

Note: If you are using Mac-OS file should be **window_dump.uix**

Answer (score 0):

As I believe this app is not allow you to take screen shot from your device and from uiautomator as well.

As I am also getting same error but when I used to get the screenshot of other app it works fine but in the case of my app its not allowed to take screen shot using uiautomator.

So better way for now to get allow it by developer in test version of app so it works to get the element of app screens.

Answer (score -1):

There are two solutions :

**1. Disconnect your device and reconnect. It should work.**

OR

**2. Kill all instances of adb.exe from task manager And restart UIAutomator. It should work.**

Comment: Thanks for sharing information. I checked above mentioned both solutions but still prblm didnt solved.

Answer (score -1):

I am taking those viewer using command prompt:
 adb shell uiauomator dump
 adb pull /sdcard/windows_dump.xml
reading those id manually